# Facebook Share link with custom port

Tags: url, facebook-sharer

When I try to share a page on a site with an url like : `example.com:81/this/that` it fails  and I get an url like `http://81/this/that`.

I use django and the urlencode filter for the sharer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to provide a proper URL: `http://example.com:81/this/that`